wakeup by bus is handled in TLE9252V Can transceiver
How wakeup by bus is handled in TLE9252V Can transceiver? Based on which pins and logic, the reason would be CANTRCV_WU_BY_BUS
some demo code for CanTrcv_Checkwakeup API based on Dio module for reading and writing to the pins.

You question is unclear, currently I can only direct you to the datasheet you surely already read.
Edit your question to raise a specific problem so we can make a useful answer. Tell us what you have done so far and you forgot to post the demo code you mentioned.
